# How to use the Tooltip() function to be global

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 *file.php*, *file1.php* it is a file for the core page, *file2.php* to display the added form.
*file2.php* included to *file1.php* in a statement.
when i need to use function from *Boostraps.js*, to beautify tooltip, i call function from *Boostraps.js* in *file1.php* as follows:

```js
$('.Btn').Tooltip({
placement: 'bottom'
});
```

why tooltip() function only runs on *file1.php* only, does not work for *file2.php* included in *file1.php*
how to keep this tooltip function running in 2 different files that are included.
if calling globally I've used action just like this:

```js
$(document).on('click',function(){
// Bla bla bla ...
})
```

Comment: Do you include `bs` library only on file `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do right now use that both 2 file php at the same time/page?

If you want do something like set it globally without need to set it again.

Maybe you can try check this code.

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".btn",function(){
    var ele     = $(this);
    if(!ele.data("setthis")){ // check it. so we only bind only once
        $(this).tooltip({
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        ele.data("setthis",true); // set this to true, don't set it anymore
    }else{ // just a log. can delete it.
        console.log("Don't Set Another Tooltip");
    }
});
```

Just run it once in core page @ anything.
And jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/o8sue511/3/

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 totally separate files, so how they should communicate to each other? Are they share a core? like wordpress CMS. If not you should include same js file into both php file otherwise it wont work.

This code:

```
$('.Btn').Tooltip()
```

means be global and every where in document you find this class `.btn` turn it to tooltip, "BUT" when there is not `.btn` in document "OR" you didn't add this code in that document, you will get anything and the code will not work.

Comment: thanks, it is true to have to include js file back in file2.php